# Title tag not displaying as expected

Tags: php

I try to style the rows with a CSS class. Now the MySQL data appears on the page, and not in the title tag anymore.

Where is the mistake?

[image: Screenshot]

```
<a href="" title="

<?php
$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM tester";
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
{
?>
<p><span class="qtip-big"><?php echo $row->Name; ?></span></p>

<p><?php echo $row->Beschreibung; ?></p>

<?php
}
?>

">Testlink</a>
```

The text appears on the page and not inside of the tooltip.

Comment: Post the rendered HTML.

Comment: Pretty sure the native title attribute only takes a text string and doesn't render html. you'd have to use a data-title and have your tooltip plugin targeting that.

Comment: Small sidenote: Try to switch to mysqli instead of mysql

Comment: +1 for entertainment and funniness

Comment: don't abuse the poor title attribute and put tags into it... use `data-title` + javascript. title should give a hint for the link, w3c.org: _"Audio user agents may speak the title information in a similar context. For example, setting the attribute on a link allows user agents (visual and non-visual) to tell users about the nature of the linked resource"_

Comment: Can you give me an example how it should look like with the use of a css class?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Answer (score 1):

Your html is all wrong :) Your code does something like this:

```
<a title="<p>paragraph</p>" > anchor </a>
```

Html element are not allowed in attributes (title is an attribute, so is href / src/ alt etc)

To get multiple lines, you can do this:

```
<a title="Line1 \nline2" > anchor </a>
```

I've added `\n` which is a character for newline. Also not that 'line2' is directly attached. Though this looks stupid, it prevents a whitespace bevore 'line2'

If you have htmlerrors, you should try an [html-validator](http://validator.w3.org/), this will return the errors you have in html

Comment: Why the downvote? Please back it up so I can imporve the answer

Comment: I think this is probably the best solution to achieve what the OP is after.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the paragraph tags from your title attribute.

Answer (score 1):

first off all you should not put HTML tags inside the title. Second of all why are you putting the php scripts inside there in such a messed up way. It reduces readability. Grab the SQL contents before you put it in the title.

```
<?php
    $abfrage = "SELECT * FROM tester";
    $ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis)){
        $name=$row->name;
        $Bech=$row->Beschreibung;
    }
?>

<a href="" title="<?=$name?> <?=$Bech?>">Test Link</a>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is bad coding. If you have multiple rows in tester, $name and $bech will only have the last values. Either drop the while, or move the anchor in it

Comment: Well the issue was regarding the OP's title not getting displayed correctly so I just reformatted his code to make it more readable. And yes the fetch object will only grab the last row because the query does not have the "WHERE" clause and I assumed that OP should be smart enough to figure that out.

thanks for the feedback :D

Comment: I tried your code, but now nothing appears inside the tooltip.

Comment: Try checking the field names because i have $row->name where as you have $row->Name. The codes are similar to your original post only difference is that its outside the href tags.

Comment: I´ve changed name in Name, and it has no effect. No content inside the tooltip appears. Just an empty tooltip window.

Comment: Try printing those variables ($Name and $Bech) after the end of while command to test if the values are getting pulled from the table. If the values are not pulled then it will not be displayed in the title section.

Comment: If i print the variables i can see the data table informations.

Comment: I use this method most of the times in my code and it seems to work fine for me but I cannot say why it is not working for you. Unless you are executing the **a href** tag inside the php tag using echo.

if the tags are inside a php script using echo then it should be some one like this.
`echo "<a href='link' title='$Name $Bech'>Test Link</a>";`

Comment: Had to add <?php echo $Name; ?> etc. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM tester";
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ergebnis))
{
$Name=$row['Name'];
$Beschreibung=$row['Beschreibung'];
}
<a href='link' title='<? echo $Name?> <? echo $Beschreibung?>'>link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must escapse the contents of your html attributes. Easiest way it to use urlencode.

```
 echo urlencode("<p>".$row->Name."</p><p>".$row->Beschreibung."</p>");
```

It's worth noting as well that html is not natively going to render within a title attribute and you must use a javascript tool tip library to get this to work as you are envisioning.

Comment: This will not fix the problem, this will only turnit into `title="&gt;p&lt; paragraph &gt;/p&lt;"`. This might be ok if you use a special tooltip script, but it will not do what (I think) the topicstarter is looking for :)

Comment: @Martijin as stated in my answer it will allow you to use a js tooltip library to utilized the title tag for rich content. But the broken markup that is being seen is the result improperly encoded attribute data.